# React Native navigation v3 with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I am trying to setup react navigation v3 with redux. In the react navigation docs I can successfully set up my navigation and it works fine without redux added. However, when I attempt to add my redux `class App extends React.Component{...}` and hook up my actions it throws the following error:

Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(AuthScreen)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(AuthScreen) in connect options.

App.js

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
  auth: { screen: AuthScreen },
  main: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
      map: { screen: MapScreen },
      deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
      review: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
          review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
          settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
        }) 
      }
    })
  }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}


export default AppContainer;
```

Here is my AuthScreen I want to connect redux to:

```
class AuthScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('This is this.props in AuthScreen:')
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.facebookLogin();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>AuthScreen</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(AuthScreen);
```

I suspect I am not allowed to wrap the `<Provider>` tags around the app container like this, can someone give some insight on how this could be done?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple example to get you started with React Navigation 3.x and Redux:

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';

import Reducers from './src/Reducers';

import Preload from './src/screens/Preload';

let store = createStore(Reducers);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Preload: {
    screen: Preload,
  },
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default class App extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppContainer/>
        </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer Lucas. Keeping the code well structured!

Answer (score 5):

So, I'll post what I have and hopefully it will help. I have a separated file (AppNavigation.js) that handles all the navigation for my app. On this AppNavigation I have this:

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  <Code here>
})
```

My RootNavigator is inside the AppContainer

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootNavigator)
```

Then, on my class I render the AppContainer.

```
class AppNavigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <AppContainer screenProps={this.props} />
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppNavigation);
```

Then, on my App.js I 'connect' my store to the RootNavigator

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RootNavigator />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

So, long story short: you should wrap your MainNavigator on your Provider tag.

EDIT:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  reducer1,
  reducer2,
  reducer3...,
})

export default createStore(
  rootReducer,
  undefined,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)
```

So with these reducers you can 'connect' them to your component via mapStateToProps and use the state of the reducers on them.

Comment: Wait, what if i'm trying to connect redux for another component (updated code)? Do I need need this line `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppNavigation);` ? Or can I just `export default AppNavigation`?

Comment: if you want to connect to another component just add the reducer to that component to your store, the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are only for the container of the component, to get the state of the reducers that I need and the dispatchers. I'll edit my answer with the connect to store

Comment: What is the point of rendering the appContainer when it could be done without the render method described here (in the quick example of createAppContainer)? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/app-containers.html The example also, doesn't use `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppNavigation)`, so I was just wondering if this is necessary? Also, you mentioned that you have your RootNavigator in `AppNavigation.js`, so do you import it back in `App.js` to wrap in the `<Provider>`?

Comment: i'm only rendering the appcontainer because i need to pass props to it from the AppNavigation.js.. yes, i'm importing my root navigator to wrap on the <Provider>.. the mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are used because I have redux in my app, but you could use the mapDispatchToProps , it's good practice in react-native to have your component do only stuff components do, and all your other functions you'll have on your dispatch

Comment: how do you access screenProps inside RootNavigator?